# Updating Blender 2.79 script to 2.80 -> mesh.uv_textures.new() fails with Mesh Object has no attribute 'uv_textures'

Tags: mesh, scripting, uv

I am updating a .tri file importer that worked in Blender 2.79.  Modifications to enable registration work.  But I cannot create a new empty UV map to dump the imported uv data to.  I am not the original author of the script.

My question is how do I do the following in Blender 2.8 python API?

Currently this fails with the message that the mesh object has no 'uv_textures' attribute.

I suspect these changes relate to the new implementation of nodes such that I have to access and create several other objects before I can create an empty UVMAP where I can dump the imported uv data.  And I suspect that if I were able to create the uv, then the rest of the code would probably work.

Code below:

```
mesh.uv_textures.new()

uv_pos = []
tmp_buffer = file.read(FLOAT_LEN*2*header.uvNum)
if len(tmp_buffer) < FLOAT_LEN*2*header.uvNum:
    errlog = logging.getLogger("TRI_OT_import")
    errlog.error("\n----=| Tri Import Error |=----\nEOF reading UV Coordinates\nShould read " + str(header.uvNum) + " UVs with \n" + str(FLOAT_LEN*2*header.uvNum) + " bytes but only read " + str(len(tmp_buffer)) + "\nTRI file has valid header, but file appears to be corrupt")
    printCollectedData(errlog, header)
    raise ValueError("Error reading TRI file")
for i in range(header.uvNum):
    data = unpack('<2f', tmp_buffer[FLOAT_LEN*2*i:(FLOAT_LEN*2*i)+(FLOAT_LEN*2)])
    uv_pos.append((data[0], data[1]))

numUV = len(uv_pos)



#I'm assuming that tri files will always have 1 UV per vertex, but i wasn't able to conirm this for sure.. so:
if numUV != len(verts_list):
    errlog = logging.getLogger("TRI_OT_import")
    errlog.error("\n----=| Tri Import Error |=----\nNumber of verticies differs from number of UV coordinates\nTRI file has valid header, but file appears to be corrupt\n   !! Since \'Base Verticies\' != \'UV Coordinates\', file is probably corrupt.\nHowever, if TRI file is *not* corrupted, then it is possible that Author\'s\nassertion regarding TRI files always correlating V and UV array indices\nmight be wrong.\n   Probably should post if you see this error and are sure file is not corrupt")
    printCollectedData(errlog, header)
    raise ValueError("Error reading TRI file")


# NOTE --- For future reference. UV's are placed "on a vertex" but indirectly. Each loop contains one vertex index that is supposed to be tied into
# a polygon face (there will be face*3 loops for a triangulated mesh) and each "loop" contains the uv. This allows for things like smoothing since a
# single vertex item can have different data depending on the face being looked at ("coming from a different direction").
#     therefore, the "loop_indices" can be misleading. This is NOT "The face-vertex index" but is an index into the loop array itself. To get the actual
# vertex index out of the face (the colleciton of 3+ loops), you must dereference the loop as well. So mesh.loops[mesh.polygons.loop_indices[0]].vertex_index
#     HOEWEVER, TRI files are of the style where, when a vertex at a locaiton needes alternate info (differnt UV), the vertex is just duplicated. So, even
# a vertex location needs more than one set of data, each vertex only has one set of data.
#     Meanwhile, the uv_layers has the uv coordinates in the same indexing order as mesh.loops. So, uv_layers[0].data[5].uv is intended to be the uv
# coordinates of loop number 5 in mesh.loops, and that is how uv are "placed" on vertex (the vertex of a particular face)
#
tmp_buffer = file.read(INT_LEN*3*len(mesh.polygons))
if len(tmp_buffer) < INT_LEN*3*len(mesh.polygons):
    errlog = logging.getLogger("TRI_OT_import")
    errlog.error("\n----=| Tri Import Error |=----\nEOF reading Face Vertex Index to UV Index array\nShould read " + str(len(mesh.polygons)) + " indicies with \n" + str(INT_LEN*3*len(mesh.polygons)) + " bytes but only read " + str(len(tmp_buffer)) + "\nTRI file has valid header, but file appears to be corrupt")
    printCollectedData(errlog, header)
    raise ValueError("Error reading TRI file")
lidx = 0
for i in mesh.polygons:
    data = unpack('<3I', tmp_buffer[INT_LEN*3*lidx:(INT_LEN*3*lidx)+(INT_LEN*3)])

    mesh.uv_layers[0].data[ i.loop_indices[0] ].uv = [ uv_pos[data[0]][0], uv_pos[data[0]][1] ]
    mesh.uv_layers[0].data[ i.loop_indices[1] ].uv = [ uv_pos[data[1]][0], uv_pos[data[1]][1] ]
    mesh.uv_layers[0].data[ i.loop_indices[2] ].uv = [ uv_pos[data[2]][0], uv_pos[data[2]][1] ]
    lidx = lidx + 1

del uv_pos
```

Comment: Its now mesh.uv_layers.new() instead of mesh.uv_textures.new()

Comment: Ron,  Thanks a million!   That got me through the UV's all by itself.  Thanks!